# Set and Get static variables values through static method in different classes in java

Tags: java, android, class, static

Lets say I have 3 Classes: `A`, `Data`, and `B`

I pass a variable from class A which sets that passed variable to a `public static` variable in class Data with Data's class `method` `setData()` and trying to get the same value (which i was assigned in `class A`) in class
`B` using Data's class `method` `getData()`.

methods in Data class are `public` `and static`

> public class Data{
>
> public static string nameD;
>
> public static void setData(String name){ nameD = name; }
>
> public static String getData(){   return nameD; }
>
> }
>
> public class A{
>
> String nameA="Test";
>
> Data.setData(nameA); 
>   }
>
> public class B{
>
> String nameB;
>   nameB = Data.getData(); 
>   println(nameB);
>   }

But gives null string in `class B`.

How can i do that.?

Comment: try putting  nameB = Data.getData(); println(nameB); in the constructor.

Comment: This is very strange, what are you trying to do here. It looks very scary code. Where are your constructors?

Comment: This code won't compile. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: @MartínMarconcini i want to set a class member's value in another class `1` and trying to get same value in another class `2`.

Comment: But do you realize that the code is a mess? Without seeing more code, it's very hard if not impossible to tell what your problem is. Who is creating the instances of A and B? Where are these classes created? In Which order? Etc. It's clear that what you're thinking that you're doing is not exactly what you wrote. Obviously setting a class member's value is trivial, and getting the value through a getter is also trivial, your problem lies in code we cannot see yet…

Comment: @alfasin i am trying to access member's value of `class A` through `class Data` in `class B`

Comment: @LASIAF post a code that compiles and then show us on which line it fails in run-time (preferably post the stacktrace and the line where it fails).

Comment: @MartínMarconcini i am trying to access member's value of `class A` through `class Data` in `class B`.

Comment: @alfasin
sorry i could not explain my problem appropriately.

Comment: @Martín Marconcini
sorry i could not explain my problem appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just call first class A to set the value for class Data then call class B to get the value inside the data.

ex:

```
public class A{
     String nameA="Test";
     public A() {
         Data.setData(nameA);
     }
 }

 public class B{
      String nameB; 
      B() {
         nameB = Data.getData(); 
         System.out.println(nameB); 

      }
 }

 public class Data{

    public static String nameD;

    public static void setData(String name){ nameD = name; }

    public static String getData(){ return nameD; }
  }
```

then if u made the following, you will got ur value
   new A();
   new B();

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the object and have a static field in the object you pass.

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid code, because you cannot execute a statement like `Data.setData()` outside of any method.

If you put this code in a method inside class A and then call this method in your main program in the correct order (before calling `getData()`), it will still be very confusing code, but you should get your desired result.